# Flutter add dropdownbutton to head of textinput field

Tags: flutter

I got an flutter app it got textformfield (what a suprise :) So I want to put a button to head of the inputfield. Let me explain what I mean
[image: This is the now]
Currently like this .The button bellow changes the language but I want to do is

The code

Input

```
TextFormField(
            validator: (value) {
              if (value.isEmpty) {
                return isempty;
              }                 
              value = value.trim();            
              return null;
            },
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              hintText: 'The hint is you have to give entry',
              labelText: "entry somethingg",
              fillColor: Colors.white,
              border: new OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                borderSide: new BorderSide(),
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

the button

```
MaterialButton(
            onPressed: buttonState ? _buttonChange : null,
            child: Text(langbtn),
            color: Colors.greenAccent,
          ),
```

I want to make it like this.
[image]
I searched and find dropdown button but i couldn't fit it. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

I have something similar in my application:

```
class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  const Test({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _TestState createState() => _TestState();
}

class _TestState extends State<Test> {
  String val = "english";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        DropdownButton<String>(
          value: val,
          onChanged: (String newValue) {
            setState(() {
              val = newValue;
            });
          },
          items: <String>['english', 'spanish']
              .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
            return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
              value: value,
              child: Text(value),
            );
          }).toList(),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: TextField(
              //* textfield config *//
              ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```